# In Mediawiki, how do I get the PageSaveComplete to execute?

Tags: mediawiki

Using Mediawiki 1.39 I have a number of hooks defined in a custom extension's extension.json file:

```
{
    "name": "Dcycle Mediawiki Starterkit Custom Extension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "author": [
        "Albert Albala"
    ],
    "url": "http://github.com/dcycle/starterkit-mediawiki",
    "descriptionmsg": "dcycle-mediawiki-starterkit-desc",
    "license-name": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "type": "other",
    "requires": {
        "MediaWiki": ">= 1.39.0"
    },
  "Hooks": {
        "SpecialStatsAddExtra": "CustomExtension\\Hooks::onSpecialStatsAddExtra",
        "PageSaveComplete": "CustomExtension\\Hooks::onPageSaveComplete",
        "PageDeleteComplete": "CustomExtension\\Hooks::onPageDeleteComplete"
  },
    "JobClasses": {
        "customExtensionUpdateWordCount": "CustomExtension\\Job\\UpdateWordCount"
  },
    "AutoloadNamespaces": {
        "CustomExtension\\": "src/"
  },
    "MessagesDirs": {
        "CustomExtension": [
            "i18n"
        ]
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

The SpecialStatsAddExtra and PageDeleteComplete hooks get executed as expected, but the code in the PageSaveComplete hook never even gets called. I can put a syntax error in the CustomExtension/Hooks.php and no error happens when I save a page.

The [PageSaveComplete](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/PageSaveComplete) seems to exist in MediaWiki 1.39, how can I make the hook be called when I save a page?

My hooks file looks like:

```
<?php

namespace CustomExtension;

use CustomExtension\JobScheduler\JobScheduler;

/**
 * All CustomExtension's external hooks.
 */
class Hooks {

    public static function onSpecialStatsAddExtra( &$extraStats, $context ) {
        error_log('onSpecialStatsAddExtra is called', 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");
        return TRUE;
    }

    public static function onPageDeleteComplete(\MediaWiki\Page\ProperPageIdentity $page, \MediaWiki\Permissions\Authority $deleter, string $reason, int $pageID, \MediaWiki\Revision\RevisionRecord $deletedRev, \ManualLogEntry $logEntry, int $archivedRevisionCount) {
        error_log('onPageDeleteComplete is called when I delete a page', 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");
        return TRUE;
    }

    public static function onPageSaveComplete(\WikiPage $wikiPage, \MediaWiki\User\UserIdentity $user, string $summary, int $flags, \MediaWiki\Revision\RevisionRecord $revisionRecord, \MediaWiki\Storage\EditResult $editResult) {
        error_log('onPageSaveComplete is never called when I save a page', 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");
        return TRUE;
    }

}
```

Comment: The "PageSaveComplete" hook gets called within a deferred update (meaning after the response has been sent) so you will not be able to see if the hook has been called from the page. You will be able to see this from the logs (see wgDebugLogFile and wfDebug). Maybe you want MultiContentSave hook instead of onPageSaveComplete hook?

Comment: Currently having a similar problem, also on 1.39 but saw the same on 1.35 and 1.37 as well. Hook is executed on an edit but not page creation. Special:Version shows the hook is registered but it's not executed at all.